# How can i fix problem of "illuminate/filesystem conflicting version" while installing laravel breeze?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-breeze

I am trying to install Laravel breeze but having this error:

```
$ composer require laravel/breeze --dev
Using version ^1.2 for laravel/breeze
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/breeze
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/breeze[v1.2.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require illuminate/filesystem ^8.42 -> found illuminate/filesystem[v8.42.0, v8.42.1, 8.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/breeze ^1.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/breeze[v1.2.0, 1.x-dev].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Here is my composer.json (i.e. fresh install of laravel):

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell composer to update your packages which conflicts with the target package requirements using `--with-dependencies` and `--with-all-dependencies` commands. [Read more](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u)

So, you can tell composer to update your package to resolve the conflicts.

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev -W
```